# A painter has three different jars of paint colors available, in colors green, yellow, and purple.

Tags: probability

A painter has three different jars of paint colors
available, in colors green, yellow, and purple. She wants to paint something
abstract, so she blindfolds herself, randomly dips her brush, and paints on the
canvas. She continues trying paint jars until she finally gets some purple onto
the canvas (her assistant will tell her when this happens) and then she stops. Assume that she does not repeat any of the jars because her assistant removes
a jar once it has been used. So the sample space is
$S = \{(P),(G, P),(Y, P),(Y, G, P),(G, Y, P)\}$

Find the Probabilities of each of the following events:

$\{(P)\}$

$\{(G, P),(Y, P)\}$

$\{(G, P),(G, Y, P)\}$

$\{(Y, G, P),(G, Y, P)\}$

$ \{(P),(Y, P)\}$

What I did was this:

$P\{(P)\} = \cfrac{1}{5}$ since $(P)$ is just one of the five outcomes in the sample space

$P\{(G, P),(Y, P)\} = \cfrac{2}{5}$ since $(G,P)$ and $(Y,P)$ are two of the five outcomes in the sample space

$P\{(G, P),(G, Y, P)\} = \cfrac{2}{5}$ since $(G,P)$ and $(G,Y,P)$ are two of the five outcomes in the sample space

$P\{(Y, G, P),(G, Y, P)\} = \cfrac{2}{5}$ since $(Y,G,P)$ and $(G,Y,P)$ are two of the five outcomes in the sample space

$P\{(P),(Y, P)\} = \cfrac{2}{5}$ since $(P)$ and $(Y,P)$ are two of the five outcomes in the sample space

But the final answer in the back of the book says this:

$P\{(P)\} = 1/3;$

$P\{(G, P),(Y, P)\} = 1/3;$

$P\{(G, P),(G, Y, P)\} = 1/3;$

$P\{(Y, G, P),(G, Y, P)\} = 1/3;$

$P\{(P),(Y, P)\} = 1/2;$

I have no idea where they got these values from. Where did I go wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: No no no no.  You have some profound misunderstandings.  See Eevee Trainer's answer, as a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the events in your sample space are not all equally likely.

For instance, she has a $1/3$ chance to pick purple at the start, so the probability of event $(P)$ is $1/3$. (Hopefully, that much is intuitively obvious: three pots to pick from, one is chosen at random.)

However, on the other hand, to get $(Y,P)$ for another example, she has to pick yellow, and then purple: that is a probability of $1/3 \cdot 1/2 = 1/6$ ($1/3$ for yellow, then $1/2$ for purple once yellow is removed).

The notion of probability being equal to

$$\text{probability} = \frac{\text{# of desired events}}{\text{total events in sample space}}$$

only applies whenever each event in the sample space is equally likely.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't think about whether they were equally likely or not (tricky question!), so something like $(G,Y,P)$ would be $\cfrac{1}{3} \cdot \cfrac{1}{2} \cdot 1 = \cfrac{1}{6}$ correct? where $\cfrac{1}{3}$ means probability of picking green first, $\cfrac{1}{2}$ means probability of picking yellow second, and then $1$ means probability of picking purple last since it's the only color left yes?